# Долго конвентируются геокоординаты в индексы. Почему?

Tags: python, массивы, geocoding

У меня есть вот такой код. Но отрабатывает он очень долго, а когда подставляю в массив огромное кол-во геокоординат, вообще почти не грузит:

```
from dadata import Dadata
array = [
//тут геоокординаты, их очень много
]
list1 = [x[0] for x in array]
list2 = [y[-1] for y in array]
for lat in list1:
    for lon in list2:
        token = "ваш API ключ"
        dadata = Dadata(token)
        result = dadata.geolocate("postal_unit", lat=lat, lon=lon, count=1)
        indexes = [x['value'] for x in result]
        for x in indexes:
            print(indexes, end=",\n")
```

Вот пример массива из геокоординат:

```
[52.385036, 84.763009],
[52.388213, 80.657897],
[52.274828, 78.953496],
[52.287781, 82.766584],
[52.214745, 80.800136],
[52.17111, 85.853564],
[52.14118, 82.183407],
[52.189769, 82.359872],
[52.127614, 82.816261],
[52.112208, 81.853429],
[52.162609, 80.089299],
[52.070531, 84.104589],
[52.060798, 81.210693],
[51.882111, 84.421577],
[51.88767, 81.01115],
[51.983077, 81.393428],
[51.97166, 82.146423],
[51.859528, 79.470441],
[51.709304, 82.482519],
[51.78003, 80.361947],
[51.668199, 82.734335],
[51.660071, 84.320418],
[51.568223, 82.025519],
[51.443815, 80.703792],
[51.482331, 81.684384],
[51.508002, 80.352658],
[51.35033, 81.902432],
[51.393191, 79.794831],
[52.616503, 81.226396],
[53.421015, 83.517091],
[52.181123, 85.965224],
[51.844369, 82.955985],
[51.487272, 81.211466],
[53.316553, 81.496474],
[53.372435, 78.916513],
[53.823356, 80.070614],
[53.197442, 84.600603],
[53.223102, 79.895371],
[53.172777, 80.090521],
```

Что делать? Буду очень благодарен за помощь. Спасибо большое зарание

Comment: В открытый доступ токен выкладывать не стоит. Зачем вам два генератора, если можно сразу идти по списку `array` и в метод `geolocate` подставлять `lat=array[index][0], lon=array[index][1]`.

Comment: Выбивает ошибку, иначе бы я не делал два генератора.

Comment: а что за ошибка возникает?

Comment: что-то связанное с list и int. Сейчас постараюсь ее отобразить. Но дело не в этом, вы знаете, в чем причина того, что данные конвентируются максимально долго? Проблем с соединением нету.

Comment: У дадаты есть некоторые ограничения по частоте запросов и их количестве в сутки на бесплатный аккаунт (что-то около 10к) предположу, что вы фтыкаетесь в лимиты. И да... Не возьмусь судить о качестве либы поскольку ее даже не пробовал, там все пркрасно через requests тянется

Comment: Да, я знаю про лимиты. Но дело в том, что когда я подставляю свой массив с геокоординатами в код (там их меньше 10к), то конвертация происходит для одного индекса около 10 секунд. Раньше такого не было

Comment: Попробуйте без либы запросы покидать. Года 2 назад, когда клиентскую базу в порядок приводил я плотно с ними занимался. Никаких проблем подобных вашей не встречал, но (повторюсь) либу не юзал

Comment: Благодарю за совет.

Comment: А если поменять ваши циклы на `for lat, lon in array:`? Вы понимаете, что если у вас в `array` 10K элементов, то вы делаете 100М запросов? Цикл в цикле - это вы в квадрат число операций возводите.

Comment: Благодарю. не думал об этом. Переписал код, теперь все работает. Спасибо еще раз.